# Android Studio Androidmanifest.xml contains garbage characters

Tags: android, xml

I am creating an app on Android Studio 0.6.1. The Androidmanifest.xml file contains only special characters and shows that the manifest file is read only. When I am building the app I get an error "Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]". I am on Windows 7 64 bit.

Can I run the app on the emulator without the manifest file?

Please help!

Comment: The manifest must be a well formed XML file. You need to fix that before going any further.

Comment: It seems like you are using a **compiled** manifest file. Probably **taken from some apk**, without decompiling it first...

Comment: Please post the manifest file here.

Comment: @Henry The XML is valid but the APK installer on device does additional checks on the binary version of the manifest and there's some problem there.

Comment: @DerGolem Not likely. More likely that there are just some misplaced or missing constructs in the manifest we are not seeing yet.

Comment: @Iaalto Just a wild guess, since we can only **suppose** what's happening... ;)

Comment: Dear All, 
Thank you for your responses. I am trying to paste the content of the manifest file, but can't on this text box. The manifest file contains lots of '??????****' other swigly-wiggly characters.